# Error using cv2.imshow (Unspecified error)

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I'm following [this tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) to make corner detection and I have to use cv2.imshow. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = '1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray = np.float32(gray)
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

#result is dilated for marking the corners, not important
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None)

# Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image.
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow('dst',img)
```

I got this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /root/mc-x86-2.7/conda-bld/opencv-3_1482254836916/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 545
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: /root/mc-x86-2.7/conda-bld/opencv-3_1482254836916/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:545: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

So, I installed libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config but it didn't solve the problem. The error message said to run cmake but where? There is no CMakeLists.txt file in my drive.

Then, I follow some answers on this website like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044206/7334162): first, I downloaded OpenCV directly on the website and I run cmake, make and make install. All is okay but I still have the same error when I use Anaconda but it got another message when I open Python from /usr/bin/python:

```
init done 
opengl support available
```

For the moment, I can't show my image. What I have to do?

Comment: You can install opencv with : conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv. It won't need building.

Comment: I already did it. It doesn't work; I get the same error.

Comment: Did you enable GTK when running CMake? It may be disabled by default.

Comment: You may find this helpful in setting up conda while setting up from source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30281466/3051961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my question, I had two problems:

1. From /usr/lib/python, I was unable to show the image but I didn't
   have an error;
2. With the Anaconda Framework, the function imshow wasn't implemented.

For the **first** problem, it was really easy because I didn't read the documentation correctly. It says, about the `cv2.waitKey()` function:

> Besides binding keyboard events this function also processes many
>   other GUI events, so you MUST use it to actually display the image.

So, I just have to call cv2.waitKey(1) after cv.imshow() to show the image.

For the **second** problem,

- I used a manual method to solve it (I'm not sure it's the best but it works). I replaced all the `libopencv*` files in the `/home/user/anaconda3/lib` folder by the `libopencv*` files in the `/usr/local/lib/` folder.
- After that, I had to update the `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so' file with the '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so' file.

---

There is also a cleaner alternative but you should restart the installation process to do it. When you run the `cmake` command, the parameter `-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` have to refer to your anaconda folder (for me, it's `/home/pierre/anaconda3/`). After that, you just have to continue the installation as usual:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Now, you can use OpenCV with Anacaonda (but only with Anaconda; it doesn't work if you load `/usr/bin/python`).

Answer (score 0):

Install `cv2` using `pip` from within the conda environment, using the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

The wheels provided by `pip` do not contain this error.