# Python Opencv imshow error

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I try on some trial..
i build

> cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
>   -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D
>   BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..

and if i try on python :

> import cv2
>
> print(cv2.**version**)
>
> 3.2.0

my full code :
(https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/)

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("/home/reigin/Pictures/games.jpg")
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("Over the Clouds", image)
cv2.imshow("Over the Clouds - gray", gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i got error on this :

```
cv2.imshow("Over the Clouds", image)
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

i set my dpk-configure :

```
reigin@reigin-K43SA:~$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

if i do other than show my image no any problem..

can't help :

[opencv 3.0 python imshow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450602/opencv-3-0-python-imshow-error)

http://vinllen.com/solve-error-libgtk2-0-dev-and-pkg-config-when-install-opencv/

http://answers.opencv.org/question/57945/opencv-gui-with-gtk-2-solved/

https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable

Thanks for pay attention and help..

Comment: Maybe it's help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151514/matplotlib-plot-window-wont-appear

Answer (score 2):

You might be using the pip opencv-python that doesn't support GTK. Your python bindings must come from your build of opencv.

Check your `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` folder and make sure you have a `cv2.so` file from your compilation and installation of opencv, and that you're not using the package from pip's opencv-python in `dist-packages`.

See here: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Here was my Cmake line to prepare for installation:

`cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -DWITH_QT=OFF -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..`

Do note that this assumes you've installed the appropriate libgtk via sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev.

This is what CMake should spit out:

> --   GUI:
>
> --     QT:                          NO
>
> --     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.30)
>
> --     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.48.2)
>
> --     GtkGlExt:                    YES (ver 1.2.0)
>
> --     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
>
> --     VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.2.0)

Comment: I had this happen on Ubuntu 18.04. The packages installed by pip were the culprit. I removed the pip installed packages for `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python`, and then forced a re-install of the apt packages for `python3-opencv`.